# Dynamic form:select and form:option in Spring form tags

Tags: java, javascript, spring, spring-mvc, jstl

Consider the Following scenario:

I am using Spring form tags to help process a form. I am using the a  accompanied by the  tags. The values are injected into the select using an ENUM. However now there is a need to make the options dynamic and dependable on another control in the form. Depending on the value select in the other control show and hide certain option(s) or add more option(s). I have looked quite hard and researched but spring tags don't support this sorta use case. How do I overcome this issue.

I have a solution in mind but don't know if its the best. Set the cssClass attribute on the options and show and hide the options using jquery/javascript.

Please suggest a suitable solution if you have encountered this problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need Jquery for that. One option is to create a Text File for each possibility.  Each file will hold the new options along with html replacement text (see below). Then use JQuery to watch for the changing of first select.

```
Text File

    <option>Bar</option>
    <option>Bar</option> 

Script

     $("#first-choice").change(function() {
           $("#second-choice").load("textdata/" + $(this).val() + ".txt");
        })
```

You can find the other options detailed here [here](http://css-tricks.com/dynamic-dropdowns/)